# ISAPI_Rewrite Version 3 get all query string parameters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, isapi-rewrite

I have a given URL:

http://www.simtalltd.com/hebrew/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=15&Itemid=29

And I need to get all the string after: http://www.simtalltd.com/

Like this: 
hebrew/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=15&Itemid=29

I've tried this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /index.asp?rewrite_url=$1 [QSA,L,NU]
```

But I just get: hebrew/index.php

What is the correct code?

Comment: Check all of your query parameters. You will get all the query paraters in `index.asp`

Comment: I need to get them all in: rewrite_url not as parameters

Comment: That means i will get them as: rewrite_url='hebrew/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=15&Itemid=29'

Answer (score 0):

Peace of cake! Try using:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+))$
RewriteRule .* /index.asp?rewrite_url=%1 [NC,QSA,L,NU]
```

OR you can try to match body of the request and querystring separately:

RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+)$
RewriteRule (.+) /index.asp?rewrite_url=$1\?%1 [NC,QSA,L,NU]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but Sorry but both did not work.  The first one returns error: Unknown expression on line #22: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+))$  The second one returns just: 'hebrew/index.php?option=com_content'  Still missing the full string: 'hebrew/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=15&Itemid=29'

Comment: Oh, it's a typo in in the brackets: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+)$